# Phonegap Stand alone (Offline) Application

Tags: c#, android, mysql, json, cordova

I currently develop one web based software (Like library) (In PHP with MySQL) and now I Plan to develop that for smart phone and desktop. So I came to phonegap for smart phone. but now how can I grab data from my MySQL database to app? is it possible with JSON ? How ?

Other Question is that how can I use that app which develop in Phonegap while device is not connected to internet? My Same problem is with windows based software which I'm going to develop in C#.

Thanks...

Any type of help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to grab data from your MySQL database, you will need to create some PHP controller on your server to which you will send POST/GET requests from your app to retrieve/update data.

to have the app working offline, you must store previously downloaded data within devices database or introduce some caching solution (angular provides one, for example).

Comment: Ok, but what to do while phonegap app work online, how I display data ?
is AJAX is solution ?

Comment: AJAX = POST/GET requests = online. when offline, you need to get previously saved data from DEVICES LOCAL database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use GET/POST method in php to return the database result have wrap the whole sql result in `json_encode` function
i.e 
  `echo json_encode($result);`

in your offline storage you can use [websql](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) which will store it in your device storage.
since its deprecated you should probably use [indexeddb](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) for localstorage.

yes ajax will be most commonly used like `$.getJSON();` methods but my favorite is

```
        var jsonp = document.createElement("script");
        jsonp.type = "text/javascript";
        jsonp.src = "http://foo.com/api/ad?foo_var=4345&callback=displayinfo";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(jsonp);

function displayinfo(data) { //do your stuff }
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me how can I store database in indexeddb from Mysql via PHP ? when App online, its store data to offline for offline use

Comment: @ShivamPandya you shouldn't store whole database in mobile storage the app will be slow if u do it. take look at indexeddb link i provided to store data in local.